# Superscripting in PPT out of XL

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I am trying to create some slides out of XL, but am being challenged by the footnotes.
What I want to is fill the footnotes section with multiple footnotes, whereas each row starts with a superscripted number. Can anyone tell me how I can get that done?

I have tried some solutions I found online, but I am not able to just superscript one character.

Thanks for your help

s

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you started; the code's written to run w/in PPT and will need some mods for you to run it from w/in Excel:

```
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oPres As Presentation
Dim x As Long

' for example purposes, we'll do this IN PPT
' and use the current presentation
Set oPres = ActivePresentation

' and we'll work with slide 1
Set oSl = oPres.Slides(1)

' rather than using PPT's own footnotes, I'd simply
' add my own text box ...
Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 500, 500, 50)

' and work with it ...
With oSh
    ' add your text:
    .TextFrame.TextRange = "1One line of text" & vbCrLf _
        & "2Two lines of text, the second a bit longer" & vbCrLf _
        & "3New we are three lines of text"

    ' subscript the first character of each line up to 9
    On Error Resume Next    ' in case there are fewer lines
    For x = 1 To 9
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(x).Characters(1, 1).Font.Superscript = True
    Next
    ' and the first two characters of each line past that
    For x = 10 To .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.Count
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(x).Characters(1, 2).Font.Superscript = True
    Next
End With
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. Will test it as soon as the "holiday pile" has been processed :D